# Exception raised during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I just add a timepicker in my layout. It works fine if the TimePickerMode is clock, but when I change it to spinner, it shows this error: `Exception raised during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class`

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.willlian.apolloyios.SetupTime"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And, post the layout that results in the crash. Posting a layout that does *not* result in a crash does not help us.

Comment: @Yashasvi  It works when I run the emulator, so there is no error in the logcat. But it just dones't work when I design the user interface in the xml preview.

Comment: @CommonsWare It works when I run the emulator, so there is no error in the logcat. But it just does't work when I design the user interface in the xml preview.

Comment: It's rendering problem.

Comment: I have the same problem with a datepiker if I remove spinnner mode the rendering works fine. I wasted time to solve, it is annoying! -_-